# if data matches from list to data range in another column update cell in same row as matching data

Tags: excel, compare, formula

I need to update the QTY number in column G "Quantity left in stock" (sheet is called Stock) when the item selected from the list in a different sheet column C (sheet is called Log) matches

How it will be used - Select item from list in column C on "Log" sheet, fill in QTY taken from stock column E on "Log" sheet

"Stock" sheet automatically updates the QTY left in stock of the item selected from the list on "Log" sheet

Sheet that needs QTY updating:

[image]

Sheet with list and QTY input

[image]

I can't find any way to do this I have been looking for hours

Comment: Will there be more rows on Log-sheet?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `SUMIF` function like this:

[image]

When your Log worksheet looks like this:

[image]

If you don't want to create a `Qty Logged` column, then make your formula in Column G subtract the `SUMIF` from Column F:

```
=F2-SUMIF(Log!$C$2:$C$10,Stock!$B2,Log!$E$2:$E$10)
```

Of course you should expand the ranges to whatever you need. Even better would be to use a [dynamic named range](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-dynamic-named-range/) to identify the different data areas.